# links 2.7 and magnet links

Tags: linux, console, lynx, magnet-links

I use transmission-daemon and web interface for downloading torrent and text browsers (links, lynx).

How I can handle magnet-links in text browsers?

I added x-scheme/magnet with transmission-daemon in applications, but I get message 'Unsupported URL scheme'.

Answer (score 0):

You probably tried to set the `magnet:` URI handler in the system (like Gnome).

Unfortunately *links* uses its own URI handlers configuration. You can either set it from the UI: <kbd>F10</kbd> > **Setup** > **Mail and telnet** > **Magnet program**. (or directly in the `~/.links2/links.cfg` as `magnet` option) Magnet URIs are supported in *links* since version 2.3.

The handler for *transmission-daemon* should look like

```
transmission-remote -a %
```

The character `%` gets replaced by the magnet URI.